# Shortcut in startup folder does not load the right settings for Visual Basic Application

Tags: vb.net-2010, boot, application-settings, autorun

Just recently I've started with Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express and I am creating an application which loads a URL into the browser component.

One of the settings that the user is able to configure is to 'start the app when windows launches'. When this checkbox is checked and the user saves his preferences I create a shortcut in the microsoft startup folder so the application is ran when windows starts up.

I do so using the following code:

```
My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True).SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim startup As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
IO.File.Copy(Application.ExecutablePath, startup & "\ApplicationName.exe")
```

The problem is, than when I use the the shortcut that Visual Basic makes on install, located on the desktop or start menu programfolder, it loads the settings defined by the user. But when the shortcut from the startup folder is ran, it loads a completely 'new' application sort of, with all the settings on default.

Anybody that knows what I might be doing wrong? I've searched the internet alot and also looked on StackOverflow topics like [copying app shortcut to startup folder VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740227/copying-app-shortcut-to-startup-folder-vb) (which didn't work for me)

Any help would be highly appreciated. If you need more info, please ask and I'll look it up asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not creating a shortcut, you are copying the executable file to the startup folder !!
this copied executable won't find a config file near it so it will create a new one ! that's why it shows default values ..
to make a shortcut import the "Windows Script Host object model" from the "COM" tab in project->refrences->add...

```
Dim oShell As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
Dim oShortCut As IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShortcut

oShell = New IWshRuntimeLibrary.WshShell
oShortCut = oShell.CreateShortcut(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) & _
                                                    "\" & GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath) & ".lnk")
Dim s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
With oShortCut
    .TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath
    .Arguments = ""
    .WorkingDirectory = GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
End With
oShortCut.Save()
oShortCut = Nothing : oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll try it out first thing tomorrow and let you know if it worked for me or if I still have problems.

Comment: beware of one thing: adding the value to the registry and adding the shortcut to the startup folder will make the application launch twice at system startup !!

Comment: Ah yes that's logical. I'll only add it to the startup folder and not in the registry. That's an easy approach and will solve the issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Running into some, I guess 'minor' things. GetFileName and GetDirectoryName are functions I'll have to still write or am I wrong? Since Visual Basic 2010 Express does not recognize them. Sorry if this is an obvious question, I'm still very new to this.

Comment: Scratch that! I fixed it by searching the amazing internet ( :P ) and changed it into: System.IO.Path.GetFileName() and System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()

Comment: Uh-oh. When I log out of Windows and then log back in, it tries to start the application and i get two errors saying:

    Can't initialize the application (0x0000006).

However, when I manually run the .exe from the startup folder the application works like a charm. Even loads the right settings.

Comment: (I think this might be because the .exe was created from a debug run and therefore can't find the right resources?) Going to test it with a published build now. I'll get back on this.

Comment: Seems like I was right, because it was linked to the debug build it had trouble finding the right resources and therefore was unable to run. *Note to self* When making autoboot applications test them from a build and not a debug run.

Comment: Ok for people that might run into this themselves and run into this post: if you want to delete the shortcut afterwards use this:

`Dim objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If      objFSO1.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath) & ".lnk") Then
objFSO1.DeleteFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) & "\" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath) & ".lnk")
End If`

Comment: for System.IO.Path.GetFileName() just import System.IO.Path to be able to use GetFileName() in a short presentation ..

Comment: I see! I'll use that from now on. Makes the code shorter and more readable I think. I don't know why but for a couple of hours your solution worked, however now the application picks a clean setting from the startup folder once again. Didn't change a thing about the creation of the shortcut. However every time you save the settings it remakes the shortcut. Maybe I have to have a check that makes sure the shortcut doesn't excist and if not, create a new one? Could that be the problem maybe?